# LInux java class from process id pid

Tags: java, linux, centos

I am a newbie to linux. I am trying to find a command that displays 
pid and java class.

I tried:

```
ps -C java -o pid
```

but it only showed me pid, not java classes.

So I used a different command:

```
ps -ef | grep java"
```

It showed me a full library of JAR files and associated java classes. However, I don't need all of that information, I need only to display pid and java class.

The problem that I am facing is that sometimes the java processes take like 100M of memory and I can only know the pid with the command java  on it by using linux command:

```
top
```

But it couldn't find which java program is the one responsible for this. It will help me to debug that java file for memory leak.

Comment: There are cases where this is not possible, for example when you are running a jar and no class is specified (i.e. it uses the one defined in MANIFEST.MF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps aux | grep java
```

try this command and you can list of java process.
[or]

JPS will be helpful

[JPS,JSTAT,JMAP,JSTACK,JHAT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things8/index.html)

you can run jps command it will show the pid value and based on these pid value others command will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use java's `jps` command available from Sun Java.